# Is Spring Framework 5.x compatible with Oracle WebLogic 12c (12.2.1.3.0)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

In my application I am trying to implement latest Spring Framework 5.x but i am not sure that Spring 5.x is compatible with Oracle WebLogic 12c (12.2.1.3.0) or not as on UNIX environment we are having Java 8 and Oracle WebLogic 12c (12.2.1.3.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For reference please see: [Spring Boot Weblogic 12c](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-weblogic)